# LaTeX formatting in Word using Rmarkdown and flextable

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, flextable

I have a table that contains column headers with `LaTeX` formatting (e.g., `Lower CI$_{95\\%}$`). When I render the table in `HTML` or `PDF` format using `knitr::kable`, they display the correct formatting, but prints verbatim using `flextable::regulartable`.

Does `flextable::regulartable` not handle `LaTeX`, or am I missing the argument (e.g., `escape = T`) to specify `LaTeX`? And if it's not supported, will it be eventually?

It works in `pander`, but `flextable` provides much better formatting options (aside from the apparent lack of `LaTeX` support).

Comment: Why not simply try it? At least the "does .... have the same..." will be answered then. For the rest I would guess that the documentation and o/or roadmap for flextable would be a good source...

Comment: I have tried it and it prints as-is. I don't think the documentation mentions anything about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flextable is designed to output using Word's bespoke xml formatting. It is not designed to interpret LaTeX formatting, so you've not missed out arguments which would turn this functionality on or off.

The package and the officeR package which goes along with it are written and supported by David Gohel, and as you've mentioned flextable does a very good job of outputting tables to Word, which R Markdown does not do well at all. As far as I can tell there are no plans to implement LaTeX formatting in flextable. David Gohel's flextable GitHub page is linked here for reference: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/index.html

Comment: Much appreciated explanation! David's documentation is quite thorough and helpful but I was checking to see if I had missed something. I may just  simplify the headers in the `flextable` output for Word, but keep it for the final output in PDF/LaTeX output using `knitr`/`kableExtra`.